# ADB doesnt list device

Tags: android, linux, list, adb

I have a Samsung Galaxy A3 2015 device, with completely broken black screen.
The device works. I am trying to connect it to ADB so I can pull the information from it. When I connect the pone with my Linux machine via USB, the phone name appears in files, but I can't access it because the screen is locked. So i want to access it with ADB. I downloaded the ADB and it works fine.

**The problem is that it doesn't recognize the device, when I type `adb devices` , empty list appears.**

I read alot about it (I wouldn't post this question if I haven't) and I tried the following solutions: create `adb_usb.ini` file in the `.android` directory, `create 70-android.rules` file in the `etc/` directory, and add the vendor ID and other info there. Still the problem persist.

My OS is Ubuntu 16.10.

Maybe I should also mention that I didn't have the USB debugging mode enabled on my phone when the screen broke. I don't know how to turn it on now.

Comment: download this PdaNet+ software and enable while your device is connected vis USB  download link: http://pdanet.co/a/

Comment: Did you tried **adb kill-server**?
Do you have **USB Debugging activated** on the device?